# Updating react-navigation button's state according to component's state

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have right button in react-navigation's header that is clickable, and should represent boolean value such as "selected".
Once user click on the button I want to update this value in the component's state, and reflect this change in navigation bar by changing the icon.

I know I can use setParams to send handler & initial state in componentDidMount as explained in many places, however I didn't understand how can I **update** the icon based on the new state, once user clicks on it.

I know also this can be easily solved with Redux and may use it eventually, but trying to understand first if there's another solution **not** involving state management modules.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is simply to call setParams from the same handler that updates the component's state, however this is not very nice since I need to update **both** component's state & navigation bar's state.

Maybe someone can comment if there's a cleaner solution.